# Searching for any articles where one column matches any of multiple regular expressions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a very specific challenge I can't seem to find an answer for, after all my searching. I am looking to search for an article in MongoDB where the 'content' column matches any one of multiple possible regular expressions.

The general idea is, I want to take in a word and then return any column which matches that word as well as the word with any suffix. For example:

If user enters, "establish", I want to search for articles where the content column includes any of the following: "establish", "establishment", "establishes", "established", etc...

I can generate the list of possible strings to search for myself, but how do I use .find in MongoDB to search my Articles?

My code currently looks like this, which works perfectly fine for searching for ONE string, I just need to search on MULTIPLE:

```
// get all articles with phrase = ?
router.get('/articlesByPhrase', async (req, res) => {
  const { person_id, phrase } = req.query;

  try {
    const articles = await Article.find({
      person_id,
      content: { $regex: phrase, $options: 'i' },
    })
    res.json(articles)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})
```

I'm thinking I need to generate a RegExp using all my possible strings but I'm not quite sure how to pull that off. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are all the cases known that `establish`  could be succeeded with? Or is anything allowed until the word ends?

Comment: There are many different solutions to it. As long as one does not precisely know the use case and its condition(s)/specification(s), something as simple as e.g. `/^establish/` (the regex form of `.startsWith('establish')`) might already be sufficient enough. So, how does the string might look like that one *"... just need(s) to search on MULTIPLE"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the root of the word isn't going to change and you know exactly what suffixes you are looking for, then going off of the example you gave, you can use a regexpr like so:

```
"establish(?:ment|es|ed)?\b"
```

In the above string, the expression `(?:<blah>)` is called a non-capturing group. It is used to match a group of characters (without the need to refer back to them, say when when doing a replace). Inside this group, you can specify multiple options you want to match and split them with the separator `|`.

The `?` at the end specifies that you want to match 0 or 1 of the preceding element. Finally the `\b` matches a word delimiter (whitespace, punctuation, etc.)

Keep in mind that whatever regex string you form has to be fed to a Regexpr constructor, so you need to be mindful of properly escaping characters (here's a [reference](https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping)). This gives:

```
var regex_string = 'establish\(\?:ment\|es\|ed\)\?\\b'
```

Javascript has a handy way of of getting around this by using `String.raw`:

```
const regexString = String.raw`establish(?:ment|es|ed)?\b`
```

Comment: nope ... have you tried yourself? You are using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html), but it is already close.

Comment: still nope ... since the regex pattern is written as string, and therefore needs to be fed to a `RegExp` constructor, it needs some more escaping. You still didn't try.

Comment: ... oh man ... do you actually try yourself before you post code ... `var regex_string = String.raw('establish(?:ment|es|ed)?\b')` ... fails immediately ... it has to be `const regexString = String.raw\`establish(?:ment|es|ed)?\b\``

Comment: Forgive me, I've never used Javascript so was trying to go off of reference. Thanks for being patient and helpful!

Comment: Thank you! This was hugely helpful, both of you. I will post what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help. I basically used Ali Dowair's answer. But here's what I ended up with:

```
// get all articles with phrase = ?
router.get('/articlesByPhrase', async (req, res) => {
  const { person_id, phrase, all_forms } = req.query;
  var regExp;
  if (all_forms === 'true') {
    const { suffixes } = forms;
    const suffixInserts = suffixes.join('|');
    regExp = String.raw`${phrase}(?:${suffixInserts})?\b`
  } else {
    regExp = String.raw`${phrase}\b`
  }
  try {
    console.log(`searching with :${regExp}`)
    const articles = await Article.find({
      person_id,
      content: { $regex: regExp, $options: 'gi' },
    })
    res.json(articles)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})
```